# split commas separator to new line in js

Tags: javascript

I have a function that scrapes from youtube and it works fine. The issue is the data I scrape is in 1 line separated with commas so I wanted it to split it to be 1 data per line. I used the `split(",").join("\n")` method to split my string but the problem with that is if the specific data has a comma inside it it will also split it into a new line. How can I split my data into a new line but ignoring the comma inside the data itself just apply `\n` to the data separator. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

```
data = " this is data1, this is data2, this is data,3"
the current split is: this is data1
                      this is data2
                      this is data
                      3
expected split : this is data1
                 this is data2
                 this is data,3
```

```
async function scrape(url) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0});

    const textSelector = 'h3 > a > #video-title'
    const textData = await page.$$eval(textSelector,  elems => elems.map(el => el.textContent)

    browser.close();
    var string = textData + '';
    var formattedStringTd = string.split(",").join("\n")
    
    console.log({formattedStringTd})

    let data = formattedStringTd

    try {
        // Write data in 'Output.txt' .
        fs.appendFileSync('FilePath', data)
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post example of dataset too

Comment: just added an example. @MatthewSpence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by your request you mean JS should split a string where there are multiple commas that separate different data elements that cannot be identified as being separate, I'm affraid this cannot be done.

Your data elements should be **at least divided by some unique separator** or have a common element that makes the identification process much easier.

> **Golden Star**: split(",").join("\n") -> split(", ").join("\n")

Above answer seems to be the only solution  in case there is no blank space after third dataset comma.

Answer (score 0):

- Please add space after comma

```
split(",").join("\n") -> split(", ").join("\n")
```

Comment: that won't help. For example, if ```data = " data1, data2, data, 3``` data, 3 is still a data therefore shouldn't be split.@golden star